# Play VIMEO video Android

Tags: android, vimeo

Android's `VideoView` can play **YouTube** videos if you extract **RTSP** link. Is there any way to play **VIMEO**'s video that way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782818/how-to-play-vimeo-video-in-android-videoview check that... I guess the only way of playing it is via webview